# Wordpress on Heroku and localhost with different databases: Can't log in to Heroku WP dashboard

Tags: wordpress, heroku, xeround

As the (long) title suggest, I have a Wordpress blog that is running on localhost for development and Heroku for production. I modified the `wp-config` file so that when the site is on localhost, it pulls a local database and on Heroku it pulls a Xeround database.

I can log in just fine on localhost, but I can't on the Heroku version.

When I go to `http://myappname.herokuapp.com/wp-login.php` and I enter information, it just refreshes the page.

Oddly, when I go to `http://myappname.herokuapp.com/wp-admin` it auto-redirects to `http://myappname.herokuapp.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fmyappname.herokuapp.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1` and after entering information it redirects to the login screen im stuck on above.

I have tried:

- setting the `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` options in my wp-config.
- setting the above fields in my respective databases
- messing with the `.htaccess` file

Any help in this matter would be *greatly* appreciated! I can not get this figured out!

Comment: Can you trying using this custom buildpack? https://github.com/mchung/heroku-buildpack-wordpress